# Rethinkdb: Calculate tag occurrence per user

Tags: rethinkdb

My table contains documents that look like this:

```
[{ user: { 
    key: '100' 
  },
  product: {
    name: 'Product 1',
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
  }
}, { user: { 
    key: '100' 
  },
  product: {
    name: 'Product 1',
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag3' ],
  }
}, ...]
```

I would like to create a query which would

- groupe documents by the `user.key` field (1 document per user on result),
- the `product.tags` would be an object (instead of array) with tag occurrences count for each tag.

Result example:

```
[ { user: { 
    key: '100' 
  },
  product: {
    name: 'Product 1',
    tags: {
      tag1: 2, // tag1 found 2x for user.key=100
      tag2: 1, // tag2 found 1x for user.key=100
      tag3: 1
    }
  }
}, ...]
```

I think I could do this by mapping and reducing but I have problems - I'm using rethinkdb for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
// Group by user key
r.table('30400911').group(r.row('user')('key'))
  // Only get the product info inside the reduction
  .map(r.row('product'))
  .ungroup()
  .map(function (row) {
    return {
      user: row('group'),
      // Group by name
      products: row('reduction').group('name').ungroup().map(function (row) {
        return {
          name: row('group'),
          // Convert array of tags into key value pairs
          tags: r.object(r.args(row('reduction').concatMap(function (row) {
            return row('tags')
          }).group(function (row) {
           return row; 
          }).count().ungroup().concatMap(function (row) {
            return [row('group'), row('reduction')]
          })))
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

For the following data:

```
{
  "id":  "0565e91a-01ca-4ba3-b4d5-1043c918c79d" ,
  "product": {
    "name":  "Product 2" ,
    "tags": [
      "tag1" ,
      "tag3"
    ]
  } ,
  "user": {
    "key":  "100"
  }
} {
  "id":  "39999c9f-bbef-4cb7-9311-2516ca8f9ba1" ,
  "product": {
  "name":  "Product 1" ,
    "tags": [
      "tag1" ,
      "tag3"
    ]
  } ,
  "user": {
    "key":  "100"
  }
} {
  "id":  "566f3b79-01bf-4c29-8a9c-fd472431eeb6" ,
  "product": {
    "name":  "Product 1" ,
    "tags": [
      "tag1" ,
      "tag2"
    ]
  } ,
  "user": {
   "key":  "100"
  }
} {
  "id":  "8e95c467-cedc-4734-ad4d-a1f7a371efd5" ,
  "product": {
    "name":  "Product 1" ,
    "tags": [
      "tag1" ,
      "tag2"
    ]
  } ,
  "user": {
    "key":  "200"
  }
}
```

The results would be:

```
[
  {
    "products": [
      {
        "name":  "Product 1" ,
        "tags": {
          "tag1": 2 ,
          "tag2": 1 ,
          "tag3": 1
        }
      }, {
        "name":  "Product 2" ,
        "tags": {
          "tag1": 1 ,
          "tag3": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "user":  "100"
  } ,
  {
  "products": [
    {
      "name":  "Product 1" ,
      "tags": {
        "tag1": 1 ,
        "tag2": 1
      }
    }
  ] ,
  "user":  "200"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes. It's a bit complicated. I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it.